# How to make a texture circle around each vertex

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

i'm not sure how I can get the texture to originate from each vertex but my current method seems to fall apart because of each face's orientation

[image: current material]

curent material

[image: not sure what to fix]
a gradient fanning out from every vertex
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange! It might help to have a sketch or some other form of image reference on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a gradient to go out from every vertex?

Comment: yes, im trying to get a gradient to go out from every vertex

Comment: I think your only option is to unwrap and edit the image outside of Blender to highlight the vertices then use it as black&white mask. Blender can export the wire frame image from a UV to assist.I spent quite sometime playing with the Geometry input Node with Pointiness but it did not produce the affect you wanted.